# Pygame - how to make a joystick vibrate

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, joystick, vibration

Exist a way to make a joystick vibrate directly in pygame? I know there is a way with evdev, but I want know if in pygame it's possible

Comment: I've skimmed the docs a little and I don't see any references to Joystcik vibration natively with Pygame

Comment: I've never read anything like that in the pygame docs.

Comment: Semi-related answer about using evdev - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968540/control-vibration-motors-of-game-controller-in-pure-python